# What items give the holder "killer" status in online werewolv.es?

Tags: werewolv.es

When checking a player for their ability to be able to kill, the Adjudicator role also takes into consideration any items they may be holding that night. Which items give the 'killer' status in this situation?

There are some obvious ones like Crossbows and War Spears, but what about some of the other items, such as Poisoned Darts, Dagger of Paranoia, Ankh of Retribution, Heart of Hades, and the Wolf Pelt that makes a player appear as a wolf to checks?

Will holding a Veil of Shadows, which makes the player appear innocent to all checks, override both role and item 'killer' checks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table below shows if the item modifiers the player's killer status or not if they hold the item, `-` means no change.

```
 | Item                | Killer? |
 | Crossbow            | Yes     |
 | WarSpear            | Yes     |
 | Dagger of Paranoia  | Yes     |
 | Poisoned Darts      | Yes     |
 | Gauntlet of Blight  | -       |
 | Heart of Hades      | -       |
 | Ankh of Retribution | -       |
 | Wolf Pelt           | -       |
 | Veil of Shadows     | No      |
```

The Veil of Shadows has one of the highest priorities in the game, so it will override any previous modifier applied, as per the answer to the question ["how to determine what item/mechanic overrides in online werewolf"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/360557/228155)