# Bloodhound(-type) result on Damned

Tags: werewolv.es

What does the Bloodhound get as report when checking a Damned player? Is the full role and also Damned status disclosed?

(question holds for other BH-type intel as well, like Ghoul's role check and Potion of Clarity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a player is Damned via an Aura, their evil alignment will not be revealed via role-check mechanics.

This includes a Gravedigger's check after death.