# What auras can be seen by an Aura Seer?

Tags: werewolv.es

What is the complete list of possible auras that can be detected by an Aura Seer, and what causes those auras to appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aura is another word for what the code internally calls "Player Modifiers", e.g. changing a player's witchcraft status.

If something can alter a player's properties, it's an aura.

Player Modifiers are also used to add any extra effects to players which may have an on daybreak/nightfall trigger - one such example would be `Poisoned`. These are all classed as auras and will be visible.

I did toy with the idea of making some auras invisible at one point, although this idea never made it into the code.

This question asks what [auras in werewolf override each other](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/352538/how-to-determine-which-item-role-mechanic-overrules-another-if-they-contradict/360557#360557) if, for example one gives a player a positive witchcraft status and one (such as the veil of shadows) hides that status. I will edit the answer in that question with a version of the most up to date list.

Comment: As a follow up, what causes each specific instance of each aura? For example, holding a rune causes someone to have a runic aura, holding a crossbow gives the ItchyTriggerFinger aura etc.

Comment: I don't think the site encourages the use of comments as follow up questions, I believe the preferred thing is to create a second question perhaps referencing the first with a link