# What causes specific instances of each aura (for the Aura Seer)?

Tags: werewolv.es

As a follow up to an [earlier question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/372597/what-auras-can-be-seen-by-an-aura-seer), what causes each specific instance of an aura? For example, `ItchyTriggerFinger` is caused by holding a crossbow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bloodmark    - Role - Marked by a [Bloodletter](https://werewolv.es/guides/roles/Bloodletter)

UnholyEavesdropper   - Item - Has had Hell Helm cast on them

ThreatOfRetribution  - Item - Holding Ankh of Retribution

AvatarOfRetribution  - Item Activation - Ankh of Retribution

EnduringSpirit   - Item - Holding Ankh of Possession

PossessingSpirit     - Item Activation - Player has killed player with an Ankh of Possession

RiteOfFenrir     - Role - Blessed by a [Blood Priest](https://werewolv.es/guides/roles/BloodPriest)

FenrirsPledge    - Item - Player holds Warg's Bracer

BloodSoaked  - Item - Holding a Bloody Wreath

Lycanthropy  - Item - Player holds a Wolf Pelt

DemonicEssence   - Item - Holding Abyssal Armour

HoldingWeapon    - Item - Holding any weapon

Lycanthropy  - Item - Afflicted with Lycanthropy via the Sanguine Horn

SecondChance     - Item - Holding Ankh of Reincarnation

ReincarnationSpell   - Item Activation - Ankh of Reincarnation

RunicAura    - Item - played holds a rune

Spellbound   - Item / Role - Player has had Spellbound cast on them

Whispers     - Item - Has had a Hvísla rune used on them

Poisoned     - Item - poisoned by a Poisoned Dart

Blessed  - Role - Blessed by a Priestess

Decay    - Role - Decayed by a Lich

DemonicDarkness  - Role / Item - Created by the Sceptre of Darkness or a Shadowcaster

ContagiousBlight     - Role - Innate Aura of a Fanatic

Blighted     - Role / Item - Blighted by a Player

Inebriation  - Item / Role - Has had Inebriation cast on them

Damned   - Moderator

AbysmalProtection    - Item - Holding Abysmal Armour

Pollymorphed     - Item - turned into a parrot by a potion of Pollymorph

SpittingFeathers     - Item - Player can largely speak after being pollymorphed, but some random words will still be turned into parrot noises

ImImmortl    - Item - Essence of the Ancient One (joke item)

Crippled     - Item - Has been crippled

PrimedBearTrap   - Item - Player has a primed bear trap on them

Cursed   - Item - Result of a Midnight Council Decision

Weakness     - Item - Potion of Weakness used on Player

StrongNeck   - Item - Holding an Iron Collar

PaxDemocracia    - Item - Holding Amulet of Peace

Shadow   - Role - Created by a Shadowcaster

StrengthOfFenrir     - Item - Heart of Fenrir

Tenacious    - Item - Player either holds a ring of tenacity of has had a potion of tenacity used on them

Shadow   - Item - Player holds Veil of Shadows

MartyrsProtection    - Item - a player has chosen to guard them with the Martyr's Crown

CouncilMember    - Role / Item - Has been given a seat on the Midnight Council

OverrunByRats    - Item - Player has a Rat Swarm created by the Vermin Talisman on them

Doomed   - Moderator

Vulnerability    - Item - Potion of Vulnerability used on Player